# "text format parsing error in line 1: unexpected end of input stream" error while pushing metrics

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-pushgateway, parsing-error

I am trying to push the metrics from the value I derived from the zuul logs in ansible playbook. Below is the code:

- name: Push AF Upload metrics
  win_shell: >
  curl -X POST --netrc -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '
  # TYPE artifactory_upload_duration gauge
  # HELP artifactory_upload_duration artifactory upload duration
  artifactory_upload_duration {{ af_upload_duration }}
  # TYPE artifactory_upload_size gauge
  # HELP artifactory_upload_size artifactory upload size
  artifactory_upload_size {{ af_upload_size }}
  # TYPE artifactory_upload_speed gauge
  # HELP artifactory_upload_speed artifactory upload speed
  artifactory_upload_speed {{ af_upload_speed }}'
  "https://**************/pushgateway/metrics/job/AFUpload_test"

in my zuul console, I see below:
curl -X POST --netrc -d ' # TYPE artifactory_upload_duration gauge # HELP artifactory_upload_duration artifactory upload duration artifactory_upload_duration Duration:  2  seconds # TYPE artifactory_upload_size gauge # HELP artifactory_upload_size artifactory upload size artifactory_upload_size Size:  0.128284  MB # TYPE artifactory_upload_speed gauge # HELP artifactory_upload_speed artifactory upload speed artifactory_upload_speed Speed:  0.47  MBit/s' "https://************/pushgateway/metrics/job/AFUpload_test"

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   499  100    68  100   431    805   5103 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  5940
text format parsing error in line 1: unexpected end of input stream

I can see the metrics in prometheus pushgateway, however, the value is incorrect as well as the graph I created using the metric in also just a simple horizontal line.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDHnW.png)

How to resolve this issue?

I tried putting values in quotes as well as removed the units of the value and run the curl command locally, but got the same error.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take your time to take [tour] and visit [help]. After that [edit] your post, so that it's easier for those who might want to answer your question to do so.  Additionally, please see [why we do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)